# SQL management studio and Bind variables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms

My Database development skills are fairly limited but i recently did some work in Oracle SQL developer which used bind variable (i.e. ":bv1") as a parameter place holder.

Now i have done something similar in some work im doing in MS SQL Server Management studio (2012 version) using "@BV1" as a parameter however when i'm testing the query in management studio i cant find out how to declare the parameters (i.e to give them actual values when executing). Oracle SQL used to pop up with a box to add values when you start the execution but i cant find something similar in the MS version.

EDIT: so just to give an example of what i'm trying to execute. i have a select statement with a where clause like this:

```
WHERE FIELD_NAME in ( @BV1,@BV2,@BV3,@BV4,@BV5,@BV6,@BV7,@BV7,@BV8,@BV8)
```

It when i click execute it just errors saying "Must declare the scalar variable "@BV1"." where in Oracle it would normally then prompt me to provide values for the BVs.

Comment: What do you mean? If you select `Execute` from a stored procedure's context menu you *do* get a list of parameters. What have you tried? Are you trying to use Oracle syntax in SQL Server perhaps? Why not just `exec mysproc 1` or `exec mysproc @someVariable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do this in SQL Management Studio. You would need to declare and set your variables in the script:

```
DECLARE @my_int INT 
SET @my_int = 0
```

Comment: I see... bit of an effort when i've got 40 something parameters but oh well... Thanks!

Comment: Oh God, it's pathetic....Is it the same in the newest version of SSMS (currently 18.5)?

Answer (score 1):

SSMS does not directly support parameterized queries (you could use sp_executesql if the query needs to be truly parameterized).

A template with local variables may be used to prompt for value substitution.  Press SHIFT-CTRL-M to display the substitution dialog.  Template example below.

```
DECLARE 
      @BV1 sysname = <@BV1, sysname, BV1 value>
    , @BV2 sysname = <@BV2, sysname, BV2 value>
    , @BV3 sysname = <@BV3, sysname, BV3 value>
    , @BV4 sysname = <@BV4, sysname, BV4 value>
    , @BV5 sysname = <@BV5, sysname, BV5 value>
    , @BV6 sysname = <@BV6, sysname, BV6 value>
    , @BV7 sysname = <@BV7, sysname, BV7 value>
    , @BV8 sysname = <@BV8, sysname, BV8 value>;

SELECT ...
WHERE FIELD_NAME in ( @BV1,@BV2,@BV3,@BV4,@BV5,@BV6,@BV7,@BV7,@BV8,@BV8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have to declare your variables first in a script:

```
DECLARE @BV1 AS INT = 1;
```

SQL Management Studio will not prompt to declare them for you, when executed.

Anyway in your example, it seems like you just wanted something simple like:

```
WHERE FIELD_NAME in ( 1 ,2 ,3 )
```